# Visual Studio 2019 - No Android SDK instance matching the path Android component "tools" is obsolete, please install "cmdline-tools"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, sdk, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2019 for a project. But, recently I'm facing issue as -

No Android SDK instance matching the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' path
Android component "tools" is obsolete, please install "cmdline-tools"
Trying to fallback to "tools"...
File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\android.bat' not found for 'Android SDK Core'
File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\mksdcard.exe' not found for 'Android SDK Core'
File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\emulator.exe' not found for 'Android SDK Core'

I have already uninstall and reinstalled both Xamarin and VS 2019 multiple times.

Windows 11, VS 2019 Version 16.11.5. I'm attaching the SS for your reference. Please, help me if you have any solution related to this one. Thank you.
[Android SDK and Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJY5r.png)  [Tools and version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfViJ.png) [Xamarin Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0lux.png) [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JInHp.png)

Comment: You can recheck if you have set up the Android SDK correctly ? For more , check document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows .

Answer (score 0):

I opened the device manager, clicked on New, typed in Oreo in the Name: box and clicked create.  The device manager downloaded and installed the emulators.  I needed to restart VS 2022.  This cleared up the issue.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

VS gives you links in the report. Download the zip archives from the report and place 'em to <USER_HOME>\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk\